# I'm trying to call ERC721 function throught inherited contract

Tags: solidity, nft

I'm trying to call functions of ERC721 through my NFT contract using "approve" task. Within it I'm trying to call any function (for example now it is balanceOf). But i'm getting error when I calling any getter function :(

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract NFT is ERC721URIStorage {
    constructor() ERC721("NFTforMarket", "NFT") {}

    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    mapping(uint256 => address) private _owners;
    mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;


    function mint(string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint256) {
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
        _tokenIds.increment();
        return newItemId;
    }


}
//0x0d04Be8a34282b93c552dbBbEFB5Cf7dFD5300E3
```

hardhat.config.ts

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";

import { HardhatUserConfig, task } from "hardhat/config";
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan";
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle";
import "@typechain/hardhat";
import "hardhat-gas-reporter";
import "solidity-coverage";

dotenv.config();

// This is a sample Hardhat task. To learn how to create your own go to
// https://hardhat.org/guides/create-task.html
task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
  const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  for (const account of accounts) {
    console.log(account.address);
  }
});

//npx hardhat mint --address 0x0d04Be8a34282b93c552dbBbEFB5Cf7dFD5300E3 --addressto 0x149E6e85b6D9b32702f2a14cB1A4817BA19Ede20 --tokenid 0
//npx hardhat rBalance --address <contract address> --network rinkeby
task("aprove", "aproving transfer opportunity")
  .addParam("address", "The contract address on Rinkeby")
  .addParam("addressto", "To whom")
  .addParam("tokenid", "id of NFT")
  .setAction(async (taskArgs, hre) => {
    const contract = await hre.ethers.getContractAt("NFT", taskArgs.address)
    await contract.approve(taskArgs.addressto, taskArgs.tokenid)
    //console.log(await contract.getApproved(taskArgs.tokenid))
    console.log(await contract.balanceOf("0x7e670e2807f96a6df5f936ec37ff92595cefa3e4"))
  });

//npx hardhat list --address 0x149E6e85b6D9b32702f2a14cB1A4817BA19Ede20 --addresstoken 0x0d04Be8a34282b93c552dbBbEFB5Cf7dFD5300E3 --tokenid 0 --price 1000  --network rinkeby
task("list", "listing")
  .addParam("address", "The contract address on Rinkeby")
  .addParam("addresstoken", "Token addres")
  .addParam("tokenid", "id of NFT")
  .addParam("price", "price")
  .setAction(async (taskArgs, hre) => {
    const contract = await hre.ethers.getContractAt("NFTMarket", taskArgs.address)
    const balance = await contract.listItem(taskArgs.addresstoken, taskArgs.tokenid, taskArgs.price)

  });


// // You need to export an object to set up your config
// // Go to https://hardhat.org/config/ to learn more

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      url: process.env.RINKEBY_URL || "",
      accounts:
        process.env.PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined ? [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY] : [],
    },
    ropsten: {
      url: process.env.ROPSTEN_URL || "",
      accounts:
        process.env.PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined ? [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY] : [],
    },
  },
  gasReporter: {
    enabled: process.env.REPORT_GAS !== undefined,
    currency: "USD",
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
  },
};


export default config;
```

[image]

Comment: Here is a error

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I missed --network :D